# Symfony don't recongnize ISNULL function

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to integrate the `MySQL` function `ISNULL` to my doctrine query in Symfony.

```
 $order = 'DESC';
->orderBy('ISNULL(response.value), response.value', $order)
```

Symfony did not recognize this function,it is not a by default function. It's also absent from the doctrine extensions list.

Is there any way to resolve this kind of problem ?

Comment: You could try `COALESCE` instead of ISNULL

Comment: Try `->orderBy(response.value IS NULL, response.value', $order)`

Comment: @DylanDelobel I haven't tested your suggestion but that does not look valid for a MySQL order by expression. Your suggestions seems valid for a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  I just tested his suggestion, and it seems to work

Comment: There is an [extension](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) for IFNULL which might do the same thing.

Comment: @Cerad, IFNULL must me used in SELECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A valid solution is to use this

```
->orderBy(response.value IS NULL, response.value', $order)
```

This will output a `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Also sorting descending puts the rows that have `TRUE` first